# Depositing a large amount of cash during a short visit to the US

Tags: usa, banking

I am a US citizen living in Japan. I will briefly visit the US (1 week) and will simultaneously get a fairly sizable chunk of cash while there. Rather than carrying US dollars over to Japan with me (and potentially raising the eyebrows of Japanese customs agents), I would rather deposit it in my US Citibank account and then do a wire transfer.

In Japan, ATMs in convenient stores are super convenient and will let you deposit large sums of cash (thousands of dollars). It's been 12 years since I did any cash-related banking in the US so I am totally oblivious to what my options are.

Ideally the method would:

1. Not require a visit to a bank branch (because I will have very little time in the US during banking hours)
2. Have a low chance of complication (since I will be out of the US if something goes wrong)

Comment: There is normally no issues depositing cash in the US banks just that after a certain amount it will be reported to the IRS.

Comment: @Karlson But can I do it from an ATM? Any ATM? That bank's specific ATMs? Only some ATMs of that specific bank? Only at the actual bank itself?

Comment: I am not sure about Citibank's ATMs but BofA you can do it.  But you will have to feed it 40 bills at a time.   So depending on the amount and denominations you may be there awhile.  I'd simplify and use a teller.

Comment: How much cash are we talking about?  Reporting requirements mostly kick in around $10,000.  However, don't even think about splitting your deposit into multiple pieces to get under this limit - that's illegal in itself.  A separate note - banks often have a "night depository box" which you can use to leave your cash after hours, accompanied by a deposit slip - but you have to trust them to correctly count your cash and not steal it.  If it's anywhere near $10,000 I'd take the time to go to a branch and deposit it over the counter.

Comment: @NateEldredge it would not be $10k or greater. Not looking to skirt reporting or anything of the like, just don't like carrying cash around. Good point on the night deposit boxes though.